# Rectify postgres datetime format when it conflicts

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, datetime

I am having an issue with the DateTime conflict in postgres. I have 2 columns: `date_created` and `date_updated` in a table called `profiles`. These columns are defined as below. When a row is inserted to the table, the datetime is generated byb the server.

```
    date_created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
    date_updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
```

I have a python client used psycopg2 to make the insert query, then later I switch to FlaskAlchemy for easy manage the application structure. I made some changes for `date_created` and `date_updated` for the `Profile` opject(the `profiles` table with ORM model). At this point, the client generates the datetime for both columns.

```
class Profiles(db.Model):
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now())
    date_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now())
```

Because the python client and server also generate the datetime for these columns it makes a wrong datetime format in the table and all rows inserted on the same date have the same time(they must be different). You can see the prior datetime and current datetime below.

```
> 2022-04-29 07:48:45+00          2022-04-29 07:48:45+00
> 2022-04-29 08:44:43+00          2022-04-29 08:44:43+00
> 2022-04-26 08:23:52.488335+00   2022-04-26 08:23:52.488335+00 -> conflict
> 2022-04-26 08:23:52.488335+00   2022-04-26 08:23:52.488335+00 -> conflict
```

I have found the reason for this, but I want to rectify and get the correct time for all inserted rows. Is there a way I can make it work? Really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! I want to solve the identical timestamps, the time like the one server generated

Comment: identify when the row is inserted